# Google Sheets QUERY with string dates (virtual columns) returns no results

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, virtual-column

### **Problem Statement**

I am trying to run a QUERY on a large data set, but cannot get my QUERY to return any data. It keeps giving me this error: "Query completed with an empty output".
The crux of the issue is the format the dates are in: *"2023-02-18T14:02:58.760Z"*. I need to be able to convert these date strings into dates the QUERY can understand without creating extra columns in my Sheets.

### **My approach so far and example**

I began by trying to use **DATEVALUE(LEFT(...** to convert the dates, and have made some progress.

I have recreated a simpler example of what I'm trying to do [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NakDcs9MdALMqLFD9NRmGDnkxfO9MSjFMj1AhrSYgwY/edit#gid=0).

[image]

On the left is a mock-up table of data with dates in column A in the format I have to work with (for example: "2023-02-18T14:02:58.760Z").
I want to be able to filter out dates that are not relevant.

Reading this [article](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/170382071/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-date-via-query-select?hl=en) I tried creating a virtual array to convert the string dates into dates that the QUERY can understand.
I think I'm on the right track as I can make the dates show up correctly in my sheet with the following formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2:A12,10)),A2:C12}, "SELECT Col1",0))`

However, when I add the WHERE clause, no results are returned and there are clearly dates that should come back.
Here's the formula with the WHERE clause:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2:A12,10)),A2:C12}, "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 >= date '2023-02-01'",0))`

### **Question**

How can I filter out rows with dates that don't match (I actually need to have them between two dates - a start and end date)?
I don't care if I use the technique above that I started pursuing. If there's a better way than the **DATEVALUE(LEFT(**... approach, that's fine.

*One note, in my real example I am using IMPORTRANGE from another sheet and I can't edit that sheet, so I can't add columns to it, and I also don't want to add columns to the sheet I do have edit access to, because there will be many tables and I'd need a date column for each. This is why I'm trying to create virtual columns inside my QUERY.*

## **EDIT:**

Both [saddles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22354199/saddles) and [rockinfreakshow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5479575/rockinfreakshow) provided answers that were useful and either could have been applied to my data as solutions to my problem.

However, ultimately I went with a similar approach to saddles because for my particular set of data and the date format (*2023-02-18T14:02:58.760Z*) as he pointed out, the dates can be compared as text strings without converting them to date objects. This made me realize a virtual column is not even needed in my case and there's no need for **DATEVALUE(LEFT(...**

Here's a modified approach based on saddles answer using a text comparison without the virtual column:

`=QUERY(A2:C12, "SELECT Col1 WHERE * >= '"&TEXT("2023-02-01", "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)`

This works since I am not concerned with the date format returned and this gets you output like the following (with the correct rows filtered out):
[image]

If you do need to have date objects in a virtual column, or need your returned date column modified for a specific format, then try either of the solutions mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

Another approach that you may try is this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2:A12,10)),A2:C12}, "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 is not Null and Col2 >= '"&TEXT("2023-02-01", "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0))
```

### OUTPUT

[image]

### EXPLANATION

Since you're already getting the dates in your formula, I simply removed the first empty space with `Col1 is not Null` and used the second column as the parameter for the date you wanted because I noticed that the output of the table looks like this:

[image]

### REFERENCE

- [Filtering With Dates In The QUERY Function](https://benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates)

Comment: Thank you for the great idea. I chose your answer as the accepted answer because it made me realize I don't even need a virtual column or the date manipulation. The dates can just be compared as strings as you pointed out in your answer. I added your solution to my spreadsheet so others can copy the formulas. See my edits for more details.

Answer (score 2):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=query({index(datevalue(left(A2:A12,10))),A2:C12}, "select Col1 where Col1 >= "&int("2023-2-1")&" format Col1 'yyyy-mm-dd'",0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution works great and I could use it for my real data set. I ended up choosing @Saddles answer only because it made me realize I can compare the dates as text strings and not even use a virtual column which simplified the final formula. However for others that may need virtual columns, your solution should be a great option. I've added your solution to my spreadsheet for others to copy. See my edits for a fuller explanation. Thank you!